# Unable to run glassware on google glass in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I am using Glass development kit preview(API level 19). I have created a sample app in Eclipse targeting that.Glass is been detected by device manager but this is the screen I get in eclipse when i try to run the app.[image]

I have installed the device driver for glass(XE 19.1). I am running Windows 8.1 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. If you execute in the command line : `./adb devices` , what do you get? If you are getting "Unknown device", this could be the first reason.
2. Is your Glass turned on for debugging? (enable/disable in Glass). It is required for running Glassware in Glass using USB cable.
3. Have your confirmed that you trust your computer with your Glass? It is also required.

Comment: I dint confirm that I trust my computer with the glass. thank you

Answer (score 1):

**If using Windows 8/8.1 you must first disable driver signature enforcement. Google glass driver is not authorized by Microsoft.
This guy helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfpKyj7fJCM

Answer (score 0):

Silly anwser but have you tried to reboot the Google Glass. Once I had the same issue I've just rebooted and it worked again.